# C# Razor HTMLHelper Dropdown

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Amigos estoy haciendo un **drop down list** con **Razor** y estoy tratando de obtener los valores del **drop**, pero solo obtengo el nombre que le puse en vez de sus valores alguien podría guiarme o decirme donde estoy mal?

```js
        [HttpPost]        
        public void  GetBanco() {
                
                string[] keys = Request.Form.AllKeys;
                string banco = keys[0]; // aquí el valor de banco es dropList
                // D: wtf?
                
                AddBanco(banco);
        //end method
        }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("GetBanco", "Control", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
  <label>Elija un banco:</label> @Html.DropDownList("dropList", new SelectList(new[] { "Bancomer", "Banamex", "Santander", "Banorte" }), new { required = "required" })

  <input type="submit" value="cargar" /> }

</div>
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es hacer llegar al Controller todas las opciones que declaraste en la vista? No entiendo bien lo que buscas

Comment: pues si, pero solo quiero la opción que esta selecionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenes que recibirlo como un `FormCollection`

por ejemplo;

```
[HttpPost]        
//Recibis un objeto FormCollection
public void  GetBanco(FormCollection form) {
    //"dropList" es el atributo name del input/select que queres recibir
    string banco = form["dropList"].ToString();
    AddBanco(banco);
}
```

Saludos